# Google maps direction service sends different response formats

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using javascript, google direction service
I have multiple source points on the map and one destination point. I need to find the closest source point to the destination point. As direction service works asynchronously I need to map points with their lat/lang. However the problem is that, the response format sent by direction service changes.

```
    function calcRoute(start, end) {
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, 
        function (response, status) {
            distanceCount++;
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {                    
                var dist = computeTotalDistance(response);
                console.log(dist);
                if (dist &lt; minDistance) {
                    minDistance = dist;
                    minDistanceIndex = locationsMap[response.ug.origin.Ua+""+response.ug.origin.Va];
                }
                if (distanceCount == vl.length) {
                    drawWay(vl[minDistanceIndex], fsl);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The problem occurs on the line

```
minDistanceIndex = locationsMap[response.ug.origin.Ua+""+response.ug.origin.Va];
```

**response.ug.origin.Va** and **response.ug.origin.Ua** comes from google direction service, however it sometimes changes to **response.ug.origin.Xa** and **response.ug.origin.Ya**.

Do you have any ideas why it changes from time to time? or any ideas how to deal with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to access those internal properties, they are not a part of the API so they may change.

Use only the properties/methods defined inside the specification, all data provided by the response are accessible through them,

example:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location
//returns latLng of the origin
```

Apart from that:

Your description sounds as if you better should use a [DistanceMatrixRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests)

Comment: Yep I tried the same but response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location is not usually equal to the origin I give. I guess this is because origin doesn't have to be a point on a way but start_location does. I'll give a try to Distancematrixrequest but the real problem here is; I ask to a (asynchronous) remote service for something, but it doesn't send any information in the response indicating for which request it is sent.

Comment: When you like to access the request-object passed to directionsService.route, why don't you do it? It's there, because you've created a closure from it, so you may access it inside the callback : `minDistanceIndex = locationsMap[request.origin.lat(),request.origin.lng()]`

Comment: because they are in different scopes and directionsService.route works asynchronously which means  in `minDistanceIndex = locationsMap[request.origin.lat(),request.origin.lng()]` request is not meaningful even doesn't exist.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's asynchronous or a different scope, it's a closure.

Comment: unfortunately it matters, i tried it and it doesn't work. 
BUT **the matrix service works for my problem**, HOWEVER, in asynchronous communication response should have data indicating for which request it is sent otherwise it is sometimes impossible to identify it.

Comment: I agree in that point( "should have data indicating for which request it is sent"), you may send a feature-request for that. So far, when using a closure is not an option, you may access response.ug , origin will still be a LatLng, so you may access the data by using response.ug.origin.lat()/response.ug.origin.lng() . But this will only reduce the problem and doesn't fix it, the "ug" may change too.